# (Python) Unable to properly print out a list into a string

Tags: python, list

```
def printlist(list):
    if list == []:
        print " "
    else:
        print str(list[0]) + " " + str(printlist(list[1:]))
```

When this is given a list, like `printlist(['D','R','B','T'])`, it ends up returning

```
T None
B None
R None
D None
```

I want to make this display `D R B T`. How can I do this? (WITHOUT USING `' '.join()`)

Comment: You need to return a value from `printlist`. Currently it doesn't. It just prints. So you get `none`.

Comment: I'm curious why you don't want to use `join`.  Also, `list` is a built-in function, so you might want to rename that variable.

Comment: Its also worth noting that join() is much more efficient than 'foo' + 'bar'; and is the accepted Python idiom for this sort of thing.

Comment: I believe that it is a school assignment that asks him not to use `str.join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your function *prints* a value, rather than *returning* one (which means it returns the default value of `None`)… but then, within that same function, you try to call it and use its return value. Which is, of course, `None`.

Calling `str()` on `None` doesn't help; it just gives you the string `"None"`.

If you're trying to "get back" the values that you printed to the screen and then forgot about, there's no way to do that. If you want those values, don't forget about them in the first place!

---

What you probably want is something like this:

```
def strlist(lst):
    if not lst:
        return " "
    else:
        return str(lst[0]) + " " + strlist(lst[1:])

def printlist(lst):
    print strlist(lst)
```

… which has a function that returns something and uses returned values instead of just printing, or this:

```
def printlist(lst):
    if not lst:
        print " "
    else:
        print str(lst[0]) + " "
        printlist(lst[1:])
```

… which has a function that doesn't try to use the return value it will never get.

(I've fixed two other minor things along the way—don't name a variable `list`, because that's the name of the type and you don't want to hide it, and don't check `== ""` when an empty list is already false.)

Of course it's worth noting that `strlist` in that case is just a slow and complicated version of `" ".join`, so you could just do:

```
def printlist(lst):
    print " ".join(map(str, lst))
```

Also, either way, I'm not sure where you do and don't want newlines. You add spaces at the end of lines, so presumably you want other stuff to follow on the same line (otherwise why bother with the space), but then you do `print` statements without the magic comma, which always adds a newline after each such `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def printlist(list):
    if list == []:
        print " "
    else:
        print str(list[0]) + " "
        printlist(list[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration you are executing a print() function, which terminates with a \n character -- hence the multiple line thing.

The second problem is that one of the constructors to your string is printlist(), which has no return value, hence the None value at the end.

So what you need to do first is build the string from the list, then execute one print() on the constructed string.

That is why the common idiom in python is to do:

```
print ' '.join(list)
```

because that's exactly what happens here -- join() creates a single string from the list and print is executed exactly once on the result.

It has been mentioned that join() only works on strings -- which is true -- so you can do a list comprehension instead. It has also been pointed out that Python2's "print" is technically a statement, not a function -- so, so satisfy the picky, here's another way:

```
from __future__ import print_function
def print_list(l):
    print(' '.join([str(x) for x in l]))
```

Comment: He's not executing a `print()` function, but a `print` statement. This is Python 2.x, not 3.x.

Comment: Also, `' '.join(list)` won't actually work if the list has non-strings in it.

Comment: I see I was insufficiently picky. So `print ' '.join([str(x) for x in l])`

Comment: It's not just "technically" a statement; this is a huge difference between Python 2.x and 3.x. When novices who are using a Python 2.x book with a 3.x interpreter or vice-versa come to SO bewildered and looking for help, the majority of the time, that's the reason.

Comment: And leaving out the `str` is also not just pickiness—the OP's original code clearly went out of its way to call `str` on everything (in fact, on one too many things), so just throwing that away with no comment or explanation is not a good idea.

Comment: Its always a difficult choice for me to pick between answering a beginner's question as-is when it results in non-idiomatic code (demonstrating a recursive function to build a string from a list, for example, instead of using join()), or changing the form of the answer to be more idiomatic at the risk of requiring either a lengthy explanation or glossing over a lot of fine points (such as inclusion of print_function and an in-place list comprehension). Still unsure what the right balance is.

Comment: iCodez pointed out that this guy is probably doing an assignment that requires him to write a `join`-like function from scratch. Is he right? I don't know. You can try to guess and write the appropriate answer for that case, or you can just wait for the OP to actually answer, or you can write both answers in one with a linking explanation. If you guess, sometimes you'll guess wrong, and sometimes the OP will disappear and you'll never find out—but your answer could still be useful to a future searcher, right?

Comment: Quite true. I should probably develop a library of bookmarks to issue X in lang Y answers to direct people to if I plan to participate in SO much -- it'd save a lot of typing and ambiguity.